# Best server sync software/methods

Tags: windows, backup, synchronization

I have a test server at home and a test server at the office.  I'd like to somehow sync multiple folders in both directions automatically so I can work at home and to also provide an offsite backup.

I've tried Live Sync (Microsofts own product) but it chokes on large amounts of files and seems a bit rudimentary.  Dropbox is also a bit small and does not adapt to our filesystem setup.  I have seen a few online backup services but none seemed geared to multiple computers using the same account.  I don't mind paying a monthly fee provided the service is good.

Suggestions would be greatfully appreciated!

Comment: Product and service recommendations, which is the kind of answer this type of question draws, are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of the server.. Could you use [Distributed File System (DFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft))?   I think it requires Windows 2k3 server or later, and you'd probably have to have a forest set up encompassing both domains, home and office..

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/) as a solution, there are [three versions](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html) ranging between Free (as in no cost) and everything except the kitchen sink. Should cover most use cases. Trial versions are available for the paid for versions, and if you decide you need a feature in the "Pro" version it is $50.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a few folders you can try SyncToy.

> Brief Description
>   SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos, with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.

wiki: [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy)
download: [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en)

I assume you are using VPN to connect from your home computer to your work.

Comment: He could also create a 3rd copy on a portable/flash disk to act as an intermediary if running disconnected. This is what I do, even though I have a VPN, simply for performance.

Answer (score 1):

The program that immediately jumps to mind given this problem is rsync. Although I have no experience with rsync for Windows, this looks promising: http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650